# ng-repeat with ng-transclude inside a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to create a list with custom behavior when it's content changes. I try to create a directive for this but I get a bit lost with how to combine the ng-transclude with the ng-repeat directive. Can somebody put me on track?

Html:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <mylist items="myItem in items">
       <span class="etc">{{myItem}}</span>
    </mylist>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])    

.controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.items = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
})    

.directive('mylist', function () {
  return {
    restrict:'E',
    transclude: 'element',
    replace: true,
    scope: true,
    template: [
      '<ul>',
        '<li ng-repeat="WhatGoesHere in items" ng-transclude></li>',
      '</ul>'
    ].join(''),
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {
      var parts = attr.items.split(' in ');
      var itemPart = parts[0];
      var itemsPart = parts[1];
      scope.$watch(itemsPart, function (value) {
        scope.items = value; 
      });      
    }
  }
});
```

I've got part of this somewhat working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BaQkw/)

#### EDIT:

Criteria:

- The template of the item must be defined in the view, not in the directive and it must have access to an item property in a child scope. Ideally I want to define this like it is done in the ng-repeat directive
- The directive must have access to the list so I can set proper watches and change things. If possible I would like to have easy access to the generated DOM items (I can also do it with `element[0].querySelectorAll('ul>li')` or something, It only has to work on Chrome).
- If possible I would like to reuse the logic in the ng-repeat directive because it does already do a lot of what I want. Preferably I don't want to copy the code. I just want to augment its behavior, not change it

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Solved the problem myself:

I am able to do it in the compile step ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BaQkw/2/)) by adding the `ng-repeat` attribute when the template is compiled and feeding it the content of my attribute.

#### Html:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <mylist element="myItem in items">{{myItem}}</mylist>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Javascript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])

.controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.items = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
})

.directive('mylist', function ($parse) {
  return {
    restrict:'E',
    transclude: 'element',
    replace: true,
    scope: true,
    template: [
      '<ul>',
      '<li ng-transclude></li>',
      '</ul>'
    ].join(''),
    compile: function (tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
      var rpt = document.createAttribute('ng-repeat');
      rpt.nodeValue = tAttrs.element;
      tElement[0].children[0].attributes.setNamedItem(rpt);
      return function (scope, element, attr) {
        var rhs = attr.element.split(' in ')[1];
        scope.items = $parse(rhs)(scope);
        console.log(scope.items);
      }        
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: This is great! One thing isn't working for me: in the compile's return function, `$parse(rhs)(scope)` always returns `undefined`, but I can find the right variable if I do `$parse(rhs)(scope.$parent)`. How come yours works on the child scope -- isn't `items` declared in the parent?

Comment: `items` is declared in the parent scope. Are you using isolated scope? `scope: {}` instead of `scope: true`

Comment: this does not work anymore in current angular versions. See this discussion: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7874

Comment: @ulilicht I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37756421/3078890) would be the answer then

Answer (score 14):

An alternative way to achieve this as follows.

Index.html:

```
<html ng-app='myApp'>

<head>
    <title>AngularJS Transclude within Repeat Within Directive</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src='index.js'></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller='myController'>
    <people>Hello {{person.name}}</people>
    <button name="button" ng-click="changeRob()">Change Rob</button>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js:

```
var myApp = angular.module( 'myApp', [] );

myApp.controller( 'myController', function( $scope ) {
    $scope.people = [
        { name: 'Rob'  },
        { name: 'Alex' },
        { name: 'John' }
    ];

    $scope.changeRob = function() {
        $scope.people[0].name = 'Lowe';
    }
});

myApp.directive( 'people', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',

        transclude: true,
        template: '<div ng-repeat="person in people" transcope></div>',
    }
});

myApp.directive( 'transcope', function() {
    return {
        link: function( $scope, $element, $attrs, controller, $transclude ) {
            if ( !$transclude ) {
                throw minErr( 'ngTransclude' )( 'orphan',
                    'Illegal use of ngTransclude directive in the template! ' +
                    'No parent directive that requires a transclusion found. ' +
                    'Element: {0}',
                    startingTag( $element ));
            }
            var innerScope = $scope.$new();

            $transclude( innerScope, function( clone ) {
                $element.empty();
                $element.append( clone );
                $element.on( '$destroy', function() {
                    innerScope.$destroy();
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

See it in action in this [similar plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IbNqR0854V8yXnajKSFB?p=preview). Based on this [long Github issue discussion](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7874).

Answer (score 9):

Other answers *unfortunately* does not work with newest version of angular(I checked `1.4`) so I think there is a benefit to share [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/gegemapivu/1/edit?html,js,output) I found:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('TestCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myRecords = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
  });

app.directive('myDirective', function($compile) {
  var template = '<div id="inner-transclude" ng-repeat="record in records"></div>';

  return {
    scope: {
      records: '='
    },
    restrict: 'A',
    compile: function(ele) {
      var transclude = ele.html();
      ele.html('');

      return function(scope, elem) {
        var tpl = angular.element(template);
        tpl.append(transclude);

        $compile(tpl)(scope);

        elem.append(tpl);
      };
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.js"></script>


<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="TestCtrl">
  <div my-directive records="myRecords">
    ?: {{record}}
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, nice and simple as well... Thanks!

Comment: I had to do a [whole lot of additional work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49581790/angular-1-6-component-transclusion-scope/49604551#49604551) but this answer looks essentially like what worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

Transcluding isn't necessary because `items` contains what we need to render the template.  Put another way, there isn't anything inside the element -- i.e.,  `<mylist>nothing new here we need to transclude</mylist>`.  It seems Angular will do the $watching for us too.

```
.directive('mylist', function () {
  return {
    restrict:'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: true,
    template: [
      '<ul>',
      '<li ng-repeat="myItem in items">{{myItem}}</li>',
      '</ul>'
    ].join('')
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<mylist></mylist>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/SZATE/).

Note that creating a new scope is optional, so you could comment out this line:

```
//scope: true,
```

**Update**:  You could optionally create an isolate scope:

```
scope: { items: '='},
```

HTML:

```
<mylist items=items></mylist>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/SZATE/3/).

**Update2**: based on additional info provided by Jan:

> The template of the item must be defined in the view... I would like to reuse the logic in the ng-repeat directive

Okay, so lets put it all in the view, and use ng-repeat:

```
<ul mylist>
  <li ng-repeat="myItem in items">
    <span class="etc">{{myItem}}</span>
   </li>
</ul>
```

> it [the directive] must have access to an item property in a child scope... The directive must have access to the list so I can set proper watches and change things

Following your original fiddle, we'll use a normal child scope (i.e., the child scope will prototypically inherit from the parent scope): `scope: true,`.  This will ensure the directive has access to the properties defined on the controller's scope, e.g., `items`.

> access to the generated DOM items

The directive's link function has an `element` argument.  So in the HTML above, element will be set to the `<ul>` element.  So we have access to all the DOM elements.  E.g., `element.find('li')` or `element.children()`.  In the fiddle referenced below, I have it $watch the `items` array.  The $watch callback has access to `element`, so you have access to the generated DOM items.  The callback logs `element.children()` to the console.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/SZATE/4/).

In summary, to add custom behavior to a list, just plop a directive onto a ul or ol and away you go.

Comment: You don't understand, my item template inside `<mylist></mylist>` is much more complex than than the example I give here

Comment: What else is inside -- just text, or other $scope properties?

Comment: Look, my list in real life is a list with large objects, the items contain a lot of scope properties. I just simplified my example. I want a directive which acts like a ng-repeat on a ul>li structure with isolated scope so i  can watch the items property and do stuff on the list when it changes. Like, load more items, change scrolling behavior, etc

Comment: Instead of transcluding, can you put what you need into the directive's template?  If not, I'll need to see an example of what you are trying to transclude to help you further.  Also, you can watch the entire `items` property with [$watch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$watch), but set the 3rd parameter to true for "deep checking"/object equality instead of just reference checking:  `scope.$watch('items', function(newVal) { ... }, true);`

Comment: I can put my view logic in a directive, I can also put my DOM manipulation in a controller, it's both a bad practice. I need a directive that mimics the ng-repeat directive but I want to add additional behavior. My use case is here: https://github.com/Janpotoms/google-reader-notifier/blob/master/app/popup.html look inside for #grn-items-list.  But that doesn't matter. I want a reusable component

Comment: @Jan, see Update2 in my answer.

Comment: That is basically what I have now and what I want to change. In the meantime I found a way to do it and answered my own question. Cheers.

Comment: +1 This worked for me. As soon as I removed `transclude: true` from my directive representing the `ng-repeat`ed items, things began to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem and ended up adding a little code to `ng-transclude` so it would allow watch and accept custom data from the using parent.

- this way the transcluded data have access to the grandparent scope
- and also have access to the ng-repeat data given to it.

**Usage**

**Grandparent.js**

```js
<div>{{ $ctrl.listName }}</div.

<my-list items="$ctrl.movies">
   <div>From context: {{ name }}</div>
   <div>From grandparent: {{ $ctrl.listName }}</div>
</my-list>
```

**Parent.js (MyList)**

```js
<li ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.items track by item.id">
  <cr-transclude context="item"></cr-transclude>
</li>
```

**Code changes to ng-transclude**

```js
return function ngTranscludePostLink(
   ...
  ) {
  let context = null;
  let childScope = null;
  ...
  $scope.$watch($attrs.context, (newVal, oldVal) => {
    context = newVal;
    updateScope(childScope, context);
  });
  ...
  $transclude(ngTranscludeCloneAttachFn, null, slotName);
  ...
  function ngTranscludeCloneAttachFn(clone, transcludedScope) {
     ...                                 
     $element.append(clone);
     childScope = transcludedScope;
     updateScope(childScope, context);
     ...
  }
  ...
  function updateScope(scope, varsHash) {
    if (!scope || !varsHash) {
      return;
    }
    angular.extend(scope, varsHash);
  }
}
```

Full code is at [Github](https://github.com/elpddev/cr-transclude).

A working example can be seen in [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cr-transclude-gi6fd?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).