# Angular Using Jquery Plugin issues...dynamic dropdown data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using this jquery plugin selectric and trying to hook it up with my angular drop down.

It works fine if my html for the dropdown has the options hardcoded in the html and I just do

```
    $('select, .select').selectric();
```

But if I load my dropdown data dynamically like this

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="myAddress" ng-options="address.addressLines for address in search.result.addresses" size="{{numAddressOptions}}">
</select>
```

I get a javascript error in the selectric plugin

```
TypeError: $li[index] is undefined
```

I tried adding the selectric plug in as a directive

```
 <select class="form-control" ng-model="myAddress" ng-options="address.addressLines for address in search.result.addresses" size="{{numAddressOptions}}" selectric>
        </select>
```

and my directive

```
.directive('selectric', function(){
  'use strict';
  return{
    restrict: 'AE',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      $(element).selectric();
    }
  };
});
```

Any Ideas of what could be going wrong here ?

Comment: is Angular done with its work when this is called? maybe try something like `settimeout(function () { $(element).selectric(); }, 500);`?  The link is the last method for that directive, but you've got the other ng-* attributes to contend with and I'm not sure how that impacts the lifecycle of your directive.

Comment: Yup I was thinking this as well, I will give it a try

Comment: Yup that works man ! Any idea how I can do this in a nicer way though ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since ng-options is a priority 0 directive your directive's link function cannot be guaranteed to fire after it: [Angular 1.3.7 Compile Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile).

> priority
>
> When there are multiple directives defined on a single DOM element,
>   sometimes it is necessary to specify the order in which the directives
>   are applied. The priority is used to sort the directives before their
>   compile functions get called. Priority is defined as a number.
>   Directives with greater numerical priority are compiled first.
>   Pre-link functions are also run in priority order, but post-link
>   functions are run in reverse order. The order of directives with the
>   same priority is undefined. The default priority is 0.

To achieve the desired behavior you will want to pass your objects into a directive that creates the select element in its template. This is a very good example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14586825/1861459. This should move your link method invocation to the correct part of the directive lifecycle (after the compile is completed for the directives in your template).

You would also change `restrict: 'AE',` to `restrict: 'E',` and change your HTML to something like `<selectric addresses="{{ search.result.addresses }}" ...></selectric>`

Comment: Hey Pherris, thanks a lot you have been great help. I will rewrite the directive as above. Thanks again

Comment: before rewriting, try adding terminal: true and see if that forces the order you want (updated answer with this option).