# AngularJS error when setting class in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm creating a directive that renders a list of content from a method passed in via an attribute. In addition to passing a method to get the data from, it accepts two attributes to set a class on the ul and li elements rendered in the list. When I set the class on the li element, it works fine. When I try to set a class on the ul, chaos ensues: the ng-repeat no longer works as expected and it throws an exception "undefined is not a function"

Here's a simplified version of the directive that has the issue.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]).
directive('contentList',function(){
   return {
       restrict: 'E',
       replace: true,
       transclude: true,
       scope: {
           method:'&',
           ulclass: '@',
           liclass: '@'
       },
       template: '<div class="content-list-wrapper"> ' +
                    '<div class="content-loader" ng-show="loading"><i>Loading...</i></div>' +
       '<ul class="content-list {{ulclass}}">' +
                        '<li class="content-list-repeat {{liclass}}" ng-repeat="item in items" ng-transclude></li>' +
                    '</ul>' +
                '</div>',
       link: function(scope,iElement,iAttrs){
           scope.items = scope.method();
       }
   } ;
});
```

If you remove {{ulclass}} in the class attribute of the ul element, everything works. I'm baffled why it works for the li, but not the ul.

I've setup a jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/woogychuck/wqU63/

Comment: A fellow developer just made an interesting observation. If you remove both divs from the template it works.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388247/ng-repeat-with-ng-transclude-inside-a-directive. A little hairy I know.. as I understand, the issue is that you're muddling two scopes (as the ng-repeat creates a child scope, so you can't run ng-transclude inside it).

Comment: I don't think it's an issue with the differing scopes. The liclass variable in the ng-repeat works fine, it's the ulclass that's causing the problem. It's my understanding that the ul and divs causing the issue wouldn't be creating a new scope as there are no directives being used on those elements.