# Angular.js directive transclude ngRepeat - error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create a chart directive ( not interested in existing solutions ). I want to have definable templates for each bar using a sub-directive of `bartemplate`. I want to iterate the `bartemplate` so I thought using a template with `ng-repeat` and `ng-transclude` would do the trick ... instead angular threw an error.

`Error: [ngTransclude:orphan] Illegal use of ngTransclude directive in the template! No parent directive that requires a transclusion found. Element: <div ng-repeat="bar in bars track by $index" ng-transclude="" class="ng-scope">`

http://jsfiddle.net/jt4Y2/7/

So you may ask, why the transclude? I want to be able to include any element I add to the chart (ie. a label ) and not interfere with the `<bartemplate>`.

Comment: Do you need a  restrict: 'A', in your barchart directive?

Comment: Can you also post the error?

Comment: Is [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14388247/1432478) of any help ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have several problems with your code. First you are complicating it by doing transclusions withing transclusions within transclusions. Second, you are combining directives that already do transclusions such as ng-repeat and trying to transclude within it, which just won't work.

I have provided a simplified version of your code that does what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/jt4Y2/6/

Let me try to explain what it is doing. First we have the `barchart` directive. I took the liberty of simplifying but just making the entire body act as the template for a bar rather than having a `bar-template` directive.

Because we have set `transclude: true` the actual contents inside the `barchart` div are stripped out of the dom, but made available through a `transclude` function that you can inject into the controller via the `$transclude` parameter. We take this function and save it on our controller, so we can access it later on.

The `barchart` directive is then replaced by this template:

```
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <div ng-repeat="bar in bars track by $index" render-bar></div>
 </div>
```

Notice that there is no `ng-transclude`. Instead we create our own directive `render-bar` to render the template (this avoids any conflicts with ng-repeat and it's own transclusion).

The `renderBar` directive is pretty simple:

```
directive('renderBar', function(){
    return {
      require: '^barchart',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller){
        controller.renderBarTemplate(scope, function(dom){              
          element.append(dom);
        });
      }
  }
});
```

First, we require that there be a parent `barchart` directive. In the `link` function, we can then get its controller and access the stored transclude function which we named `renderBarTemplate`.

The first parameter we pass is the scope, which makes the function link against the current scope (basically the scope provided by `ng-repeat` which gives us access to the iteration variables including `bar`).

The compiled dom is returned via the a callback (the second paramter), which we can then attach to the `<div>` provided by `ng-repeat`.

Let me know if you have any questions or need additional clarification.

**UPDATE**:

Here's a version that let's you keep the `<bartemplate>` directive:

http://jsfiddle.net/jt4Y2/10/

I added the bartemplate directive:

```
directive('bartemplate', function(){
  return {
    transclude: true,
    restrict: 'E',
    require: '^barchart',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, barChartController, transclude){
        element.remove();
        barChartController.renderBarTemplate=transclude;
    } 
  };
})
```

It is now responsible for taking its `transclude` function and storing it in the parent's controller. (so  it can later be use by the `render-bar` directive.

Also notice the `element.remove()`. This is not absolutely necessary but is simply removes the remaning `<bartemplate>` tag from the html.

Comment: Mmm you introduced me a clear idea! So I need to clarify a bit why I had the transclude on barChart - I want to include any arbitrary elements in the chart but only repeat the template defined in the `<bartemplate>`

Comment: Can you post an example of how you would use the content there?

Comment: I updated the answer with one way you could do the `<bartemplate>`

Comment: I wanna add that this works for multiple `transclusions`. I was searching for multiple transclusions with one inside a ng-repeat and found this answer above (the updated one). I initially thought it wouldnt scale but it does! The only downside is that you need at minimum a `<div ng-translude></div>` in the template.