# Transclude not injected in link function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-transclude

Here is my code

```
'use strict';
angular.module('app')
    .directive('item'
            , ["$timeout"
            , "$Service"
            , function(
                $timeout
                , $utils) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            item: '=',
        },
        transclude: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude){
        },
        templateUrl: $fsUtils.getRelativeUrl('templates/item.html'),
        controller: 'ItemCtrl', 
    };
}]);
```

My index.html:

```
<item><div>Transcluded content.</div></item>
```

transclude variable is `undefined` and ctrl variable is `proto__: Object`.
I need to inject parent scope into transcluded scope. The transclude variable is undefined. Where am I going wrong.

My angular version is 1.1.5

Thanks.

Comment: Can I see `item.html`?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the transcludeFn. Try this:

```
transclude: true,
transcludeFn: function () { /*do your stuff here*/ },
...
link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller, transcludeFn)
```

To access controller in link function you can do this:

```
var controller = scope.controller;
```

Comment: I understand that transclude is predefined by angular, in my case its undefined in my link function. Thats what the problem is.

Comment: My question is why do you want to access it in the link function? It's part of the directive definition and it will do it's job. Are you trying to conditionally turn transclusion on/off?

Comment: I want to this [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25641618/angular-transclude-ng-repeat-inside-directive#answer-27144559)

Comment: Have you ever found the solution? I currently have the same issue for some reason... this usually work something must be messed up with my code but can't see what!