# How to get ng-repeat item inside transcluded template?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-transclude

How I can use ngRepeat item inside transcluded template? Is it possible?

Directive template:

```
<ng-transclude ng-repeat="record in records | filter1 | filter2"></ng-transclude>
```

Directive:

```
  app.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
      templateUrl: '/views/directives/mydirective.html',
      restrict: 'A',
      transclude: true,
      scope: {
        records: '='
      }
    };
  });
```

Controller view:

```
<div my-directive records="myRecords">
  {{ myDirective.record }}
</div>
```

Comment: does this help?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388247/ng-repeat-with-ng-transclude-inside-a-directive

Comment: @Jony-Y, Thank you, I'm already viewed this question, but I need to hide ngRepeat inside the directive

Comment: why do you need to use transclude though? either just make it an E directive and put it inside the div or append the template to the div and manually create it... no reason to transclude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look like it from the way you're doing it.

But you can `$compile` the template in the directive to achieve this.

http://jsbin.com/mirisixodo/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 0):

(Realizing this is almost certainly too late for you to use...)

Looks like this was discussed in detail in [this AngluarJS GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7874#issuecomment-46410994), and there is, thanks to moneytree-doug, [a way to solve your issue without resorting to `compile`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7874#issuecomment-216738353).

The deal seems to be that, at least starting at AngularJS 1.2.18, transcluding creates a child scope of its own, so your iteration variable is no longer accessible.

`$parent` *is* accessible, however, and we can use that to access the iteration variable and accomplish what you're looking to do.

Building off of [Micah's jsbin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32573740/1028230)...

#### HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
  <script 
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <my-directive records="myRecords">
      ?: {{$parent.record}}
    </my-directive>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

#### JavaScript

```
var app = angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('TestCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myRecords = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
  });

app.directive('myDirective', function () {
  return {
    scope: {
      records: '='
    },
    transclude: true,
    template: 'HELLO' +
      '<div id="inner-transclude"' +
      '  ng-transclude' +
      '  ng-repeat="record in records">X</div>',
    controller: function ($scope) {
      console.log($scope.records);
    },
    restrict: 'E'
  };
});
```

#### Result

```
HELLO
?: foo
?: bar
?: baz
```

[JsBin of reasonable success](https://jsbin.com/mirisixodo/edit?html,js,console,output).

So, again, the crux of this is changing the line if your controller from `{{ myDirective.record }}` to `?: {{$parent.record}}`.