# Pass data from parent directive to child directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hey guys I have a small question.. I have a directive that has an ng-repeat and transclude and inside of it separated several other directives that need to inherit the specific object from the itteration...

I have only been able to do this with scope.$parent.. but this I don t like because if the parent changes that the scope.$parent could multiply to scope.$parent.$parent...

The question is.. how can I pass each itteration object to the children directives ? I have tried with require and maybe $braodcast.. but with these I cannot send the specific itteration object...

```
<div demo-parent>
   <div demo-child1></div>
   <div demo-child2></div>
</div>

var demo = [obj1, obj2, obj3];

demo.directive('demoParent', [function() {
    return {
       scope: true,
       transclude: true,
       template: '<div ng-repeat="d in demo" ng-transclude></div>'
    ]
}]);

demo.directive('demoChild1', [function() {
    function link(scope, el, attr) {
         scope.someInfo = the specific info from parent; // now with scope.$parent.$parent.d
    }

    return {
       scope: true,
       transclude: true,
       template: '{{someInfo}}',
       link: link
    ]
}]);


demo.directive('demoChild2', [function() {
    function link(scope, el, attr) {
         scope.someInfo = the specific info from parent; // now with scope.$parent.$parent.d
    }

    return {
       scope: true,
       transclude: true,
       template: '{{someInfo}}',
       link: link
    ]
}]);
```

demoChild1 and demoChild2 are inside the demoParent in the markup but sepparate directives

Comment: Hello, could you please add a minimal, complete, and verifiable example to your question, it would help a lot to understand your question : http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sure sorry was in a hurry here is a very dummed down idea of what I am trying to achieve

Comment: The best way to share data between directives is using a service

Comment: Yes but when I have this itteration how can I make that service share each  element in the itteration to it s specific child

Comment: can you show what that nested directive markup looks like?

Comment: simple, the service holds the entire array, each directive gets an index and takes the element in the specified index

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: @fatman, how can I access that index.. also I have pagination handled by angular so wouldn't the index reset when the next items are rendered ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do this. The root of the issue lies somewhere with transclusion scope and template scoping. I ran across a lot of great articles discussing this issue as well; [here](http://angular-tips.com/blog/2014/03/transclusion-and-scopes/), [here (really good one)](https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/transclusion-template-scope-in-angular-directives), and [here](http://sporto.github.io/blog/2013/06/24/nested-recursive-directives-in-angular/)

Also, I ran across a great SO [question and (bottom) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388247/ng-repeat-with-ng-transclude-inside-a-directive) that deserve 99% of the credit. I only adapted it to your scenario.

Your question has you using a child scope, but there is a way to do this with an isolated scope (which might be safer for you) that I'll also show.

And finally, I'm not an AngularJS expert. My answer might not be the best solution or most performant. Your use case is definitely out of the ordinary and you may want to reconsider what it is you're trying to do (or provide more info in your question and maybe we can offer a better design)

Without further ado...
For my testing purposes, I simplified your demo array, included a controller in the parent directive to define said array and declared my directives slightly differently.

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="soPOC">
    <div demo-parent>
        <div demo-child-one></div>
        <div demo-child-two></div>
    </div>
```

so.module file defining root module:

```
(function () {
'use strict';
   angular.module('soPOC', []);
})();
```

demo-parent.directive.js file defining parent directive:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('soPOC')
    .directive('demoParent', demoParent);

demoParent.$inject = ['$compile'];

function demoParent($compile) {
    var transclude;
    var template = '<div ng-repeat="item in demos"></div>';
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'EA',
        controller: controller,
        compile: compile
    };
    return directive;

    function compile(ele) {
        transclude = ele.html();
        ele.html('');

        return function (scope, elem) {
            var tpl = angular.element(template);
            tpl.append(transclude);
            $compile(tpl)(scope);
            elem.append(tpl);
        }
    }

    //deviation from your code
    controller.$inject = ['$scope'];
    function controller($scope) {
        //test array for demo items
        $scope.demos = ['test1', 'test2'];
    }
}

})();
```

demo-child.directive.js define child directives one and two:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('soPOC')
    .directive('demoChildOne', demoChildOne)
    .directive('demoChildTwo', demoChildTwo);

function demoChildOne() {
    var directive = {
        link: link,
        scope: true,
        restrict: 'EA',
        template: '<div>{{someInfo}}</div>'
    };
    return directive;

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.someInfo = scope.item;
    }
}

function demoChildTwo() {
    var directive = {
        link: link,
        scope: true,
        restrict: 'EA',
        template: '<div>{{someInfo}}</div>'
    };
    return directive;

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.someInfo = scope.item;
    }
}

})();
```

If you go with an isolated scope style, then your html changes, you can drop the link functions from the child directives and the syntax in the child directives change slightly.

HTML:

```
<div demo-parent>
        <div demo-child-one item="item"></div>
        <div demo-child-two item="item"></div>
    </div>
```

Directive:

```
    function demoChildOne() {
    var directive = {
        scope: {
            item: '='
        },
        restrict: 'EA',
        template: '<div>{{item}}</div>'
    };
    return directive;
}
```

I would read through the articles I've linked to get a better understanding for why this solution works and getting a grasp on the scoping issues between templates, transclusions and directives.
hth